# Efficiently minimize wait time between time-constrained tasks

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, optimization

I've got an array of tasks, where each task is an object with the following properties:

- `startTime`: time the task is started (`previous finishTime + travelTime`)
- `serviceTime`: time the tasks takes to complete
- `waitTime`: idle time (objective)
- `finishTime`: `sum(starTime, serviceTime, waitTime)`
- `travelTime`: time to get to next task
- `earlyStart`: task may not start before this time
- `lateStart`: task may start no later than this time

In LP terms (ignoring the boring stuff):

- Objective: minimize `waitTime`
- Subject to:

  - `earlyStart <= startTime`
  - `startTime <= lateStart`

The order is fixed & all jobs must be performed one at a time in sequential order. In the event that a feasible solution is not found, I simply return nothing, although in most cases I'm starting with a working solution, but it's not necessarily optimal. My try at this took O(n!) time, so I'm pretty sure there's a better way that I'm not considering. This seems like a pretty common problem & I'm fairly certain it's not even NP-complete, but I couldn't find the name for it to research any further. I'm writing it in JavaScript, but any ideas, links, pseudo-code, or hyper-performant C++ implementations are welcome!

Comment: You say "the order is fixed."  What choices does the optimizer get to make? Can the optimizer decide to skip a job, even though it is within its window?  How many jobs can run at a time?

Comment: Great points, I updated the last paragraph above. Only 1 job runs at a time & no job can be skipped. the optimizer can only adjust the `waitTime` variable, which in turn will affect the task's finish time, which leads to a change in the following tasks' start times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to minimizing the difference of the start time of the last task and the start time of the first task. The equivalence results from the fact that if you push the start time of any task in the middle, the overall wait time will not change (the wait time after the task is reduced by the same amount that the wait time before the task is expanded).

A simple O(n^2) algorithm for this is the following:

- Let the first task start as late as possible.
- Iterate the remaining tasks

  - Find the earliest possible start time based on the previous task
  - If this is not possible (because this time is later than `lateStart`, push the previous task as little as possible towards the start. If it then collides with the pre-previous task, do the same there and so forth.
  - If you need to push the first task before its `earlyStart`, there is no solution.

There might be no unique solution if pushing all tasks (or a subset that either contain both first and last task or none of them) by a constant amount of time is possible.

Comment: Ah, it was that backwards loop in step 2 I was struggling with. No worries about the unique solution, as it doesn't matter where the waitTime occurs. This looks great, cheers.